# Redirect output on batch file script

Tags: batch-file, dos

Im running a batch files to copy files from one location to another,
script sample:

copy "d:\Projects\proj1\attachments\23220080" "c:\attachments" 
copy "d:\Projects\proj1\attachments\23220080" "c:\attachments"

There are some 8K copy commands like above, problem is some files are missing from the location and i need to log those to a text file. Is there is any way to do.
Basically when there is any error thrown like System cannot file the file specified, those out put and script
 for eg: 
 copy "d:\Projects\proj1\attachments\23220080" "c:\attachments"
System cannot file the file specified

Needs to be logged in an output file.

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Answer (score 0):

For any single statement, you can use `||` to execute a statement on error.

```
copy %source% %destination% || echo Could not copy %source% to %destination% >> failure.log
```

This can be any statement.  If you have specific information you need to log in a variable, change the `echo` text to include that.  If you need more than one statement, you can use `call` with a batch label to go out to a full error subroutine.

```
copy %source% %destination% || call :copy_failed

....

:copy_failed
echo Could not copy file ID# %id% to %destination% >> failure.log
rem More custom error handling here
goto :eof
```

You don't say how you got the source files, but I would suggest for maintenance sake to use a `for` loop to apply this.

```
for /f %%a in (sourcefiles) do ( copy %%a %destination% || echo whoops!>>failure.log )
```

Of course, it may just be easier to modify 8k lines of code.

Comment: I have pulled list of files from Database, created a batch file with 8k copy statements and running it on app  server. Also I need to log file id too, if copy "d:\Projects\proj1\attachments\23220080 failed, in failure log it should log file id rather than the message.

Comment: You can change the `echo` line to any command you want.  If you have the ID in a variable, echo that.  You can even run a full subroutine for any statement that fails.  `copy x y || call :copy_error`

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the errors with 2> filename.

```
copy "d:\Projects\proj1\attachments\23220080" "c:\attachments" 1>copy.log 2> err.log
```

If you want them both together

```
copy "d:\Projects\proj1\attachments\23220080" "c:\attachments" 1>copy.log 2>&1
```

Same as what you would do on *nix.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%i in (d:\Projects\proj1\attachments) do (
copy %%i c:\attachments
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 echo error on %%i >>errorlog.txt
)
echo done.
```

save as copier.bat

Answer (score 0):

A **universal solution**: get your log file *in advance*!

Let's go over all possibilities in `copy sourcefile targetfolder` command(s) in next batch file named `30332428copier.bat`:

```
@echo off
copy "D:\bat\Unusual Names\1exclam!ation.txt"    "D:\test\a b" 
copy "D:\bat\Unusual Names\2exc!lam!ation.txt"   "D:\test\b a" 
copy "D:\bat\Unusual Names\3exc!lam!ati!on.txt"  "D:\test\a b"
copy "D:\bat\Unusual Names\4exc!lam!ati!on!.txt" "D:\test\n n"
```

This file covers all combination:

- The *1st* and *2nd* source files exist as *3rd* and *4th* ones don't.
- Target folder `a b` (in the *1st* and *3rd* command) exist whilst folders `b a` and `n n` don't.

Then, running next script

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions
for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1*" %%F in (
      "D:\bat\StackOverflow\30332428copier.bat"
  ) do (
    set "sourcefile="
    set "targetfldr="
    set "firstGtoken=TRUE"
    for %%H in ( %%G ) do (
        if defined firstGtoken (
            if exist "%%~H" (
                set "sourcefile=%%~H"
            ) else (
                echo source not found "%%~H"
            )
            set "firstGtoken="
        ) else (
            rem destination folder
            if exist "%%~H\\\" (
                set "targetfldr=%%~H"
            ) else (
                echo target not found "%%~H"
                rem instead echo, we could make it as follows:
                rem md "%%~H"
            )
        )
    )
    if defined sourcefile if defined targetfldr (
        rem            all ok?
        rem            What if sourcefile exists in targetfldr? 
        echo %%F %%G
        rem            in addition to (or instead of) echo, we could `execute` the command
        rem            removing leading `rem` from next line
        rem %%F %%G 
    )
)
```

we get next **output**:

```
==>D:\bat\StackOverflow\30332428.bat
copy "D:\bat\Unusual Names\1exclam!ation.txt" "D:\test\a b"
target not found "D:\test\b a"
source not found "D:\bat\Unusual Names\3exc!lam!ati!on.txt"
source not found "D:\bat\Unusual Names\4exc!lam!ati!on!.txt"
target not found "D:\test\n n"

==>
```

Eventually, we can run `30332428.bat>copylog.txt` to get desired record.

There is last question left: What if `sourcefile` exists in `targetfldr`? What if something comes wrong and the `30332428copier.bat` script hangs for some reason and therefore should be run repeatedly?